# Geolocation Field Oops! Something went wrong

Tags: 7, google-maps

I'm using [Geofield Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield_gmap) as Field in a Content Type. Each time I try to create/Add a node, the (Geofield) field display the below Error message

> "Oops! Something went wrong this page didn't load google maps
> correctly. See the javascript console for technical details."

[image]

The Steps that I did:

- Create API key For Google Map.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to apply the following patch:

```
patch -p1 < https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/fix-api-key-not-being-used-2746209-5.patch
```

I see this message:

> No such file or directory

Comment: You either download the patch locally or manually apply the changes yourself.

Comment: @Kevin but nothing wrong with my Command?

Comment: You can also use an IDE to apply a patch, such as PHPStorm, if CLI is giving you trouble.

Comment: see my update in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you see this message when you don't have in the Geolocation module the Google API Key or the Google API Key is not working well. For this you need to go to:

```
http://YOURSITE/admin/config/content/geofield_gmap
```

Write your working Google API Key and save the Configuration.

**Edit:**

To apply the patch you need download the file to:

```
sites/all/modules/geofield/modules/geofield_map
```

then go to the dir and run:

```
patch -p1 < fix-api-key-not-being-used-2746209-5.patch
```

Comment: I just update my post

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly solve it by looking at the JavaScript console for technical details. Click on F12 and view the JavaScript error.

EDIT:
If you got a missing key map error, then it is probably misconfigured and you should find a solution [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2758889).

Comment: Please not that your answer showed up in the "low quality posts" review queue. Can you think of a way to somehow improve it? That would reduce the risk it gets deleted via moderation. Good luck! PS: why not at least some "possible causes" (even if they are only guesses) what might be causing it)?